# Problem connecting to BLE devices using Flutter Blue

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to Flutter and and wanted to test out some of the BLE functionality that Flutter Blue offers. I've got the example application up and running and it finds plenty of devices around me. The problem is that I'm not able to connect to any of them. I'm currently using a second phone to emulate a BLE Peripheral, all other software such as nRF Connect for Mobile is able to connect to the peripheral and read the data it provides. The Flutter Blue example application is just stuck on disconnected when attempting to connect to the device.

Here is a typical console output when attempting to connect:

```
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): connect() - device: 73:B9:9F:25:67:DC, auto: true
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): registerApp() - UUID=44fdc1ff-3804-4ae2-ab52-3f3b6eb31e17
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): onAutoConnectionStatusCb()status =10
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): close()
```

I have managed to connect to the emulated peripheral a few times by first connecting via a different application and then "connecting" with the Flutter application. This is the output:

```
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): connect() - device: 73:B9:9F:25:67:DC, auto: true
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): registerApp() - UUID=201eaf3d-ab8a-402e-9cbf-232527fa53a8
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=8
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): onAutoConnectionStatusCb()status =10
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=8 device=73:B9:9F:25:67:DC
D/FlutterBluePlugin( 6359): [onConnectionStateChange] status: 0 newState: 2
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): discoverServices() - device: 73:B9:9F:25:67:DC
I/flutter ( 6359): connected!
D/BluetoothGatt( 6359): onSearchComplete() = Device=73:B9:9F:25:67:DC Status=0
D/FlutterBluePlugin( 6359): [onServicesDiscovered] count: 3 status: 0
```

I have read about connections not closing properly after exiting other applications and I've made sure to toggle both Bluetooth and Location services on/off as well as uninstalling other applications that might interfere with the Flutter application. I've tried allowing a longer timeout duration on connecting to make sure that the application doesn't close the connection before being able to actually connect, apart from that I'm a bit lost and can't quite put my finger on what might be wrong.

EDIT: Just wanted to add that this seems to have been a issue related to the emulated BLE peripheral. I've since been able to make it work with both an AT-09 module and a ESP32-board without problems!

Comment: You have ask the git repo too. I post here the [link](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/178) for reference.

Comment: Could this be related to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/337)? Also it was [mentioned here](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/336#issuecomment-843448815), if you are running the app in an emulated device. There could be a possibility to face this kind of issues.